# Identify non zero duplicates across columns pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following data frame:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Column1': [150, 0, 18, 9],
                   'Column2': [150, 10, 12, 14],
                   'Column3': [0, 0, 18,3]})
print(df)
```

Which looks like this:

```
   Column1  Column2  Column3
0      150      150        0
1        0       10        0
2       18       12       18
3        9       14        3
```

I would like to identify non zero duplicates across any of the columns as part of the same row (and can extend to any number of columns). Desired result:

```
   Column1  Column2  Column3  result
0      150      150        0      1
1        0       10        0      0
2       18       12       18      1
3        9       14        3      0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution you can give it a try,

```
df['result'] = (
    df.apply(lambda row: sum(row[row > 0].value_counts() > 1), axis=1)
)
```

---

```
   Column1  Column2  Column3  result
0      150      150        0       1
1        0       10        0       0
2       18       12       18       1
3        9       14        3       0
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
df['result'] = df.replace(0, np.nan).apply(lambda x: x.dropna().duplicated().max(), axis = 1).astype(int)
```

output:

```
   Column1  Column2  Column3  result
0      150      150        0       1
1        0       10        0       0
2       18       12       18       1
3        9       14        3       0
```